# If $\Gamma $ is not enumerable then $\ell_2(\Gamma)$ is not separable

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$ a set. Define $\ell_2(\Gamma)$ as the spaces of the families $(x_i)_{i \in \Gamma}$ of scalar in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{i \in \Gamma} |x_i|^2$ is unconditionally convergent

I proved that:

- $\ell_2(\Gamma)$ have inner product $<(x_i)_{i \in \Gamma}, (y_i)_{i \in \Gamma}>= \sum_{i \in \Gamma}x_i \overline{y_i}$
- $\ell_2(\Gamma)$ is Hilbert
- If $\Gamma$ is enumerable then $\ell_2(\Gamma) $ is linear isometry to $\ell_2$

I I'm trying to show that if $\Gamma $ is not enumerable then $\ell_2(\Gamma)$ is not separable, but i can not show it.

Comment: How do you define $\sum_{i\in\Gamma}$ for abitrary $\Gamma$?

Comment: @freakish A convenient definition is just as the integral against the counting measure on $\Gamma$. This definition is really just an extension of the observation that $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}) = L^2(\mathbb{N}, \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$ since the above space is just $L^2(\Gamma, \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure on $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Gamma$ is not countable (enumerable) then we have an countable family $(e_i)_{i \in \Gamma} \subseteq \ell^2(\Gamma)$ where $e_i$ is the element of $\ell^2(\Gamma)$ given by
$$(e_i)_j = \begin{cases} 1 \quad i = j \\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Note that $\|e_i - e_j \|_{\ell^2(\Gamma)}^2 = 2$ whenever $i \neq j$.

In a seperable space, you cannot have an uncountable family of vectors at least some fixed positive distance apart. Indeed, for this case, suppose $(f_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a countable dense subset of $\ell^2(\Gamma)$. Then, for each $i \in I$, there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f_k - e_i \|_{\ell^2(\Gamma)} < 2^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Since $\Gamma$ is uncountable, some $k$ must get used twice. This means that there is a $k$ and distinct $i,j \in \Gamma$ such that $\|f_k - e_i \|_{\ell^2(\Gamma)},\|f_k - e_j \|_{\ell^2(\Gamma)} < 2^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Hence, by the triangle inequality, $$\|e_i - e_j\|_{\ell^2(\Gamma)} < 2 \cdot 2^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 2^{\frac{1}{2}} = \|e_i - e_j\|_{\ell^2(\Gamma)}$$
giving a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let for $j\in\Gamma$ let $e_j=(x_i)$, where $$x_i=\begin{cases}1,&(i=j),\\0,&(i\ne j).\end{cases}$$ Then $||e_j-e_k||=\sqrt 2$; hence any dense set  must have cardinality at least $|\Gamma|$.

**Details:** Say $S$ is dense. For each $j\in \Gamma$ choose $s_j\in S$ with $||e_j-s_j||<\sqrt 2/2$. Then $j\mapsto s_j$  is an injective function from $\Gamma$ to $S$, hence $|S|\ge|\Gamma|$.